# Redirect user on login using extra field value on login form

Tags: redirect, login

I have added a field to my login form with the login_form action hook as below

```
add_action('login_form','select_contest_field');
function select_contest_field(){
//Output your HTML
?>
<p class="tml-user-pass-wrap">
  <label for="contest">Select Contest</label>
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="contest" name="contest" required>
    <option value="uppa"  >UPPA 2017</option>
    <option value="ypa">Young Photographer Award</option>
  </select>
</p>
<?php
}
```

I have a login_redirect filter to redirect users on login depending on certain conditions and which option they choose.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
//set variables
global $wpdb;   
$contests_table = $wpdb->prefix.'photocontests';
$user_meta_table        = $wpdb->prefix.'usermeta';
$site_url   =   get_site_url();
$my_info_url = $site_url.'/my-information/';

if (isset($_POST['contest']) && $_POST['contest'] = "ypa"){
    $contest_page = $site_url.'/young-photographers-award-2017/young-photographers-award-2017-upload-submit/';
}
if (isset($_POST['contest']) && $_POST['contest'] = "uppa") {
    $contest_page = $site_url.'/uganda-press-photo-award-2017/uganda-press-photo-award-2017-upload-submit/';
} 

global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
$userID =   $user->ID;
$user_info_updated = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $user_meta_table WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = 'userinfo_updated' ", $userID) );
//check if user has updated information
//is there a user to check?
if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    //check for admins
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
        // redirect them to the default place
        return $redirect_to;
    } else {
        if ($user_info_updated != 1){
        return $my_info_url;
        } else {
        return $contest_page;
        }
    }
} else {
    return $my_info_url;
}
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

When a user logins in and selects an option on the login form, they are always redirected to the $contest_page second option no matter what option is selected, in this case,

```
if (isset($_POST['contest']) && $_POST['contest'] = "uppa") {
$contest_page = $site_url.'/uganda-press-photo-award-2017/uganda-press-photo-award-2017-upload-submit/';
```

}

How can I make sure the right value for $contest_page is selected? Is the login form passing  the selected option to the function properly? Basically, someone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a mistake in your IF logic, it should have two == and not one. As it is, the first IF is giving the value ypa to $_POST['contest'] instead of comparing.

The block of IFs should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['contest']) &&  "ypa" == $_POST['contest']){
    $contest_page = $site_url.'/young-photographers-award-2017/young-photographers-award-2017-upload-submit/';
}
if (isset($_POST['contest']) &&  "uppa" == $_POST['contest']) {
    $contest_page = $site_url.'/uganda-press-photo-award-2017/uganda-press-photo-award-2017-upload-submit/';
}
```

I'm also reversing the order of the parameters because this mistake happens a lot with programmers and by making the conditions in reverse order, if you write only one = by mistake there is a syntax error and it doesn't compile: [Yoga conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: **OMG!** Thank you @dbeja. Rookie mistake I made, hopefully it won't happen again. :-)